Unable to upload project to QGIS Cloud
While I have previously been successful with publishing my QGIS project to the QGIS Cloud application, upgrading my Ubuntu Linux system had resulted in potentially broken packages. I am unsure why this is occurring; is this a sign that Python 3.12 is unable to understand my previous default Python (version 3.10)?
This is the HTML and traceback for publishing to QGIS Cloud:
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>We're sorry, but something went wrong (500)</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body { background-color: #fff; color: #666; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; }
    div.dialog {
      width: 25em;
      padding: 0 4em;
      margin: 4em auto 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-right-color: #999;
      border-bottom-color: #999;
    }
    h1 { font-size: 100%; color: #f00; line-height: 1.5em; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- This file lives in public/500.html -->
  <div class="dialog">
    <h1>We're sorry, but something went wrong.</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>



Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andrew/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgiscloud/qgiscloudapi/qgiscloudapi.py", line 670, in request
    response = urllib.request.urlopen(req).read()
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 215, in urlopen
    return opener.open(url, data, timeout)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 521, in open
    response = meth(req, response)
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 630, in http_response
    response = self.parent.error(
               ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 559, in error
    return self._call_chain(*args)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 492, in _call_chain
    result = func(*args)
             ^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/usr/lib/python3.12/urllib/request.py", line 639, in http_error_default
    raise HTTPError(req.full_url, code, msg, hdrs, fp)
urllib.error.HTTPError: HTTP Error 500: Internal Server Error

During handling of the above exception, another exception occurred:

Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/andrew/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgiscloud/qgiscloudplugindialog.py", line 1031, in publish_map
    map = self.api.create_map(self.map_name(show_notice=True), fname, config)['map']
          ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/andrew/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgiscloud/qgiscloudapi/qgiscloudapi.py", line 320, in create_map
    content = request.post(resource, data)
              ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/andrew/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgiscloud/qgiscloudapi/qgiscloudapi.py", line 585, in post
    return self.request(resource, method='POST', data=data)
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
  File "/home/andrew/.local/share/QGIS/QGIS3/profiles/default/python/plugins/qgiscloud/qgiscloudapi/qgiscloudapi.py", line 701, in request
    raise InternalServerError(msg)
qgiscloud.qgiscloudapi.qgiscloudapi.InternalServerError: <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
  <title>We're sorry, but something went wrong (500)</title>
  <style type="text/css">
    body { background-color: #fff; color: #666; text-align: center; font-family: arial, sans-serif; }
    div.dialog {
      width: 25em;
      padding: 0 4em;
      margin: 4em auto 0 auto;
      border: 1px solid #ccc;
      border-right-color: #999;
      border-bottom-color: #999;
    }
    h1 { font-size: 100%; color: #f00; line-height: 1.5em; }
  </style>
</head>

<body>
  <!-- This file lives in public/500.html -->
  <div class="dialog">
    <h1>We're sorry, but something went wrong.</h1>
  </div>
</body>
</html>



